What are the restrictions on covariance matrices of nonnegative random variables?
If $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is the covariance matrix of nonnegative random variables $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ with $\mathbb E[X_1] = \dotsb = \mathbb E[X_n] = 1$, i.e. $M_{ij} = \mathbb E[X_i X_j]-1$, then we know the following about $M$:

$M$ is positive semi-definite, because it's a covariance matrix;
the diagonal elements of $M$ are at least $0$, because $\mathbb E[X_i^2] \ge \mathbb E[X_i]^2 = 1$;
the off-diagonal elements of $M$ are at least $-1$, because $X_i X_j \ge 0$.

Can we say anything else about $M$? In other words, is any matrix $M$ satisfying the above three constraints the covariance matrix of some nonnegative random variables $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ with $\mathbb E[X_1] = \dotsb = \mathbb E[X_n] = 1$?
This question was previously asked here and answered by referring to here. But I'm not convinced that the latter answer is correct, since it involves defining a multivariate Gaussian distribution with a particular covariance matrix without first proving that this covariance matrix is positive semi-definite. Specifically, the answer makes the implicit assumption that if $C$ is a positive definite matrix whose elements are all greater than $-1$ (we may set the $m_i$ variables in that answer to $1$), then the matrix with elements $\log(C_{ij} + 1)$ is positive definite.

Given that your objection boils down to whether a matrix with elements $\log(C_{ij}+1)$ is PD if $C$ itself is, it may be better to focus in on that question.

I'd also be okay with a totally different solution that doesn't rely on that matrix being PD.

This can be understood as a special case of the multivariate form of the Stieltjes moment problem. I was able to find Theorem 2.9. of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9905215 characterizes the sequences of raw moments that correspond to a probability measure.
It appears, though I cannot fully prove it at the moment, that as long as you ensure that the second raw moments are non-negative, there should be enough flexibility to choose the higher moments to always satisfy the conditions required.
